# Remove filter parameter from Link URL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, urls, seo

I found by scanning my website with tools like ryte.com, that i has over 48k Sites / Links.

I only created like maby 25 Websites. After searching for the issue, i found out the the category pages, wich have filters like, price, color, size, that they the reason why i got so many urls.

Here in the screenshot, its really good to see. The URL is amaoni.de/shop/hundebetten and actually it's correct if the shop generates the parameters when someone is using the filter, but how can i prevent that they're not getting indexed by google? Till now, i got a no index on the whole site, because it's not finished, so all the urls are not crawled, but i will have the problem, when i go live.

Is there a way to remove the filter paramaters from the URL or is there another way to tell google to ignore those parameters?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a canonical URL:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.amaoni.de/shop/hundebetten" />
```

which will tell search engines that those pages are copies of each other (just with different filters).

You can also tell Google, via Webmaster tools, which URL parameters to ignore (your filters). See this Help Centre article: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?hl=en